# I want to fetch section wise categories in home page's sections but I am unable to do this. Only one category section is working

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I want to fetch category wise data in home page's sections but I am unable to do this. Only one category section is working

I made Category model with belongs to Section model
My Indexcontroller code

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Front;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Slider;
use App\Category;
use App\Section;

    class IndexController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(){
            $sliders = Slider::where('status',1)->get();
            $categories = Category::with('sections')->where('status',1)->get();
            //dd($categories);die;
            return view('frontend.index')->with(compact('sliders','categories'));
        }
    }
```

My Blade file

```
    @extends('layouts.frontLayout.layout')
@section('content')
    <div class="slider_block">
        <div class="flexslider top_slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                @foreach($sliders as $slider)
                <li class="slide1">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="flex_caption1">

                            <p class="slide-heading FromTop">{{ $slider['slider_title'] }}</p><br/>

                            <p class="sub-line FromRight" style="width: 60%;line-height: 20px;font-size: 16px;">{{ $slider->slider_text }} </p><br>

                            <a href="{{ $slider['button_url'] }}" class="slider-read FromLeft">{{ $slider['button_text'] }}</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex_caption2 FromRight" style="background-image: url(/images/sliders/{{ $slider['slider_image'] }});"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<section class="wrapper">
    <section class="promo_box dark  wow fadeInDown">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="promo_content">
                        <h3>go2tourism</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="pb_action">
                        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#fakelink">
                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                            Order Now
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="latest_work">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row sub_content">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="dividerHeading">
                        <h4><span>Find your best tours</span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="recent-work-slider" class="owl-carousel">
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                        @if($category['sections']['section_name'] == "Tours")
                        <div class="product">
                            <figure class="touching effect-bubba">
                                <div class="product-img">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('images/categories/'.$category['category_banner']) }}">
                                    <div class="option">
                                        <a class="fa fa-shopping-cart" href="portfolio_single.html"></a>
                                        <a class="fa fa-search mfp-image" href="{{ asset('images/categories/'.$category['category_banner']) }}"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="product-info">
                                <div class="product-title">
                                    <h3>
                                        <a href="#">{{ $category['category_name'] }}</a>
                                    </h3>
                                </div><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="latest_work">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row sub_content">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="dividerHeading">
                        <h4><span>Find your best stays</span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="recent-work-slider" class="owl-carousel">
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                        @if($category['sections']['section_name'] == "Stays")
                        <div class="product">
                            <figure class="touching effect-bubba">
                                <div class="product-img">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('images/categories/'.$category['category_banner']) }}">
                                    <div class="option">
                                        <a class="fa fa-shopping-cart" href="portfolio_single.html"></a>
                                        <a class="fa fa-search mfp-image" href="{{ asset('images/categories/'.$category['category_banner']) }}"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="product-info">
                                <div class="product-title">
                                    <h3>
                                        <a href="#">{{ $category['category_name'] }}</a>
                                    </h3>
                                </div><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="latest_work">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row sub_content">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="dividerHeading">
                        <h4><span>Find your best cars</span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="recent-work-slider" class="owl-carousel">
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                        @if($category['sections']['section_name'] == "Cars")
                        <div class="product">
                            <figure class="touching effect-bubba">
                                <div class="product-img">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('images/categories/'.$category['category_banner']) }}">
                                    <div class="option">
                                        <a class="fa fa-shopping-cart" href="portfolio_single.html"></a>
                                        <a class="fa fa-search mfp-image" href="{{ asset('images/categories/'.$category['category_banner']) }}"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="product-info">
                                <div class="product-title">
                                    <h3>
                                        <a href="#">{{ $category['category_name'] }}</a>
                                    </h3>
                                </div><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="promo_box reverse wow bounceInUp" data-wow-offset="50">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                    <div class="promo_content">
                        <h3>Do you have any questions to us?</h3>
                        <p>Please contact us without any hesitation </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="pb_action">
                        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#">                            
                            Contact Us
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
@endsection
```

Only first section's categories are showing but others section categories are not showing
Please help me

Comment: what do you mean the first section's categories? like only categories with sections named 'Tour' are showing?

Comment: only categories related to the tours section are showing. I have to show other categories related to other sections too.

Comment: so then why do you have an `if` statement that is only allowing you to show categories that have a section with name of 'Tour'? you are telling it to do this

Comment: I need to show in different html section according to their title

Comment: don't know what the problem is, seems you are doing a loop in each "section" and doing the check for that section

Comment: yes sir, I have sections like tours, stays, cars etc. and I have to show categories related to their section in different row.

Comment: which is what your code looks like it is doing ... check the `$categories` collection and make sure it has categories that have those sections

Comment: While I doing dump and die categories are fetching according to their related section but not displaying in html